# Golang- Problemas para buildar pacotes usando o shell do OhMyZsh

Tags: golang, build

$ go build src/github.com/LohanGuedes/firstapp Retorna erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo com o caminho correto para a pasta, o comando: `go build` não concluí a formação do pacote

Atualmente uso o OhMyZsh, segue o conteúdo do .zshrc:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/home/lohan/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="spaceship"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"


# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ORDER=(
  user          # Username section
  dir           # Current directory section
  host          # Hostname section
  git           # Git section (git_branch + git_status)
  hg            # Mercurial section (hg_branch  + hg_status)
  exec_time     # Execution time
  line_sep      # Line break
  vi_mode       # Vi-mode indicator
  jobs          # Background jobs indicator
  exit_code     # Exit code section 
  char          # Prompt character
)
SPACESHIP_USER_SHOW=always
SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE=false
SPACESHIP_CHAR_SYMBOL="❯"
SPACESHIP_CHAR_SUFFIX=" "

### Added by Zinit's installer
if [[ ! -f $HOME/.zinit/bin/zinit.zsh ]]; then
    print -P "%F{33}▓▒░ %F{220}Installing %F{33}DHARMA%F{220} Initiative Plugin Manager (%F{33}zdharma/zinit%F{220})…%f"
    command mkdir -p "$HOME/.zinit" && command chmod g-rwX "$HOME/.zinit"
    command git clone https://github.com/zdharma/zinit "$HOME/.zinit/bin" && \
        print -P "%F{33}▓▒░ %F{34}Installation successful.%f%b" || \
        print -P "%F{160}▓▒░ The clone has failed.%f%b"
fi

source "$HOME/.zinit/bin/zinit.zsh"
autoload -Uz _zinit
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zinit]=_zinit

# Load a few important annexes, without Turbo
# (this is currently required for annexes)
zinit light-mode for \
    zinit-zsh/z-a-rust \
    zinit-zsh/z-a-as-monitor \
    zinit-zsh/z-a-patch-dl \
    zinit-zsh/z-a-bin-gem-node

### End of Zinit's installer chunk
zinit light zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin

export GOPATH=/home/lohan/golib
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: O que te faz pensar que o problema é no `OhMyZsh`?

Comment: Na verdade, não sei se o problema é o ```OhMyZsh``` porém achei bom deixar claro q uso...

Comment: Configurou corretamente o GOROOT e GOPATH?

Comment: Não sei dizer... configurei sem nenhum tutorial, e acabei de começar com essa linguágem...

Comment: Porém minha pasta Go está localizada em usr/local/bin

Comment: O problema é o GOPATH, https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o problema não é no OhMyZsh. Você tem duas escolhas: usar o module ou o gopath.

Eu recomendo o module, basicamente você inicia o module com o `go mod init namemodule`, leia o [getting started](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) para entender melhor, e depois pode rodar o `go run` vai buscar os pacotes.

Se preferir pode usar o [gopath](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started), lembrando que tem que configurar a Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Eu passei pelo mesmo problema.

Instalei corretamente seguindo a doc oficial, no `/usr/local`, adicionei o alias `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` no `.zshrc`, mas ao rodar:

```bash
go
```

ou

```bash
go version
```

me retornava um erro relacionado ao `git` mesmo rodando o comando fora de um espoco controlado pelo git.

O problema foi junto ao Zinit que cria alguns aliás toda vez que tu abre o terminal com zsh.

Não encontrei uma forma de suprimir ele por config, mas abrindo o a folder do zinit no vsCode:

```bash
code $HOME/.local/share/zinit
```

pesquisando pelo termo `git checkout`

encontrei essa declaracao `alias {gco, go}='git checkout'`

dai so mudei pra

`alias {gco}='git checkout'`

salvei o arquivo e restartei o terminal e gg.

Provável que quando atualizar o package isso volte, se eu entrar uma solução melhor volto aqui :)